Is the probability of $X$ in the interval $[0, \mathbb{E}{[X]}]$ at least $1/2$, if $X \sim \chi^2$?
I am working on the $\chi^2$ distribution and have the following assumption:
The cumulative distribution function of a $\chi^2$ distributed random variable is greater than $\frac{1}{2}$ at the right boundary of the interval $[0, \mathbb{E}{[X]}]$.
In other words:
Let $X \sim \chi^2(n)$ be a random variable, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is the number of free parameters. We know that the expected value is $\mathbb{E}{[X]} = n$. Then we want to show that its cumulative distribution function $F_n$ evaluated at the mean is
$$F_n(n) = P\left(\frac{n}{2}, \frac{n}{2}\right) = \frac{\gamma(\frac{n}{2}, \frac{n}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})} \geq \frac{1}{2}$$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, where $P$ refers to the regularized gamma function, $\gamma$ is the lower incomplete gamma function $$\gamma(a,x) := \int_0^x t^{a-1} \mathrm{e}^{-t}\,\mathrm dt$$ and $\Gamma$ is the gamma function $$\Gamma(a) := \int_0^\infty t^{a-1} 
\mathrm{e}^{-t}\,\mathrm dt.$$
Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this or any further information (like links, papers, books, etc)? Unfortunately, the direct calculation did not work for me. Using CAS also gave different solutions.
Thanks for your help!

So you want to show that the mean of a $\chi^2(n)$ random variable is greater than its median?

Wikipedia has the asymptotic $n(1-2/(9n))^3$ for the median of a $\chi^2(n)$, so this in principle should hold, at least for large $n$.

This is equivalent to median-mean inequality for unimodal, right skewed, continuous distributions, which holds for "nice" distributions like gamma (including $\chi^2$ here), $F$, Beta, etc., but not necessarily for Weibull.

The problem $F_n(n)\geq\frac12$ is equivalent to mean $\mu$ $\geq$ median $m$ for any $\chi^2$ distribution. In the following, I will not impose the $n\in\mathbb{N}$ condition, but allow $n\geq0$. And I will establish strict inequality $F_n(n)>\frac12$.


The degenerate case with $n=0$.

Trivially, $F_0(0)=1 > \frac12$ and $\mu=m=0$. As we will see, this is the only situation where $\mu=m$, but the inequality $F_0(0)>\frac12$ is still strict.


The case of $0<n\leq2$ with a strictly decreasing pdf $f_n(x)$.

Reflect the left side of the pdf $f_n(x)$ about median $m$ to the right side and call the resulting curve $h(x)$, i.e.,
$$h(x)=
\begin{cases} f_n(x), &\text{ if }0\leq x \leq m,\\
f_n(2m-x), &\text{ if }m<x<2m,\\
0, &\text{ otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

Obviously, $h(x)$ is a pdf since the area under $h$ is twice the area ($0.5$) to the left of $m$. Let $H(X)$ be the corresponding cdf and $\mu_H$ be the mean, which is just $m$ due to symmetry of $h(x)$ by construction.

For the left side $x\leq m$, the two curves match and $H(x)=F_n(x)$.
For the middle region $m< x<2m$, because $f_n(x)$ is strictly decreasing, the reflected portion $h(x)=f_n(2m-x)$ is increasing and must be $>f_n(x)$ . Thus the areas under the curves must be $H(x) > F_n(x)$ for all $m< x < 2m$.
For the right side $x\geq2m$, trivially $H(x)=1>F_n(x)$.

In summary, $H(x)\geq F_n(x)$ all $x$ with strict inequality for $x>m$, and we established a stochastic order between $H$ and $F_n$. It follows that,
$$
\mu=\int_0^\infty 1-F_n(x)\,\mathbb{d}x > \int_0^\infty 1-H(x)\,\mathbb{d}x
=\mu_H=m.
$$


The case with $n>2$.


In this case, $h(x)$ is defined exactly as above. However, as the mode $n-2>0$, the reflected portion $h(x)=f(2m-x)$ is not necessarily larger than $f_n(x)$ for $m<x<2m$. Define their log density ratio as
$$
r(t) = \log\left[\frac{h(m+t)}{f_n(m+t)}\right] = \log\left[ \frac{f_n(m-t)}{f_n(m+t)}\right],\ 0\leq t<m
$$
which can be simplified to
$$
r(t)=t+\frac{n-2}2 \log\left[\frac{m-t}{m+t}\right]. 
$$
Its second derivative is
$$
r''(t)=-\frac{2(n-2)mt}{\left(m^2-t^2\right)^2}<0
$$
for $0<t<m$. Thus, $r(t)$ is strictly concave over $(0,m)$. But
$$ \begin{align}
r(0)&=0,\\
\lim_{t\rightarrow 0^+} r'(t)&=1-\frac{n-2}m >0,\text{ and} \tag{">" to be verified later}\\
\lim_{t\rightarrow m^-} r(t)&=-\infty. 
\end{align}$$
Therefore, the strictly concave $r(t)$ is initially increasing from $0$ and eventually decreasing to $-\infty$. There will be exactly one point $t_0\in(0,m)$ such that $r(t_0)=0$, corresponding to $x_0=m+t_0\in(m,2m)$ at which $h(x)$ crosses $f_n(x)$ from above. That is,

For the left side $x\leq m$, the two curves match and $F_n(x)=H(x)$.
For the middle region $m< x \leq x_0$, we have $h(x)\geq f_n(x)$ and thus their cdf's satisfy $F_n(x)\leq H(x)$.
For the right side $x> x_0$, we have $h(x) < f_n(x)$ strictly and thus
$$\begin{align}
F_n(x) &= 1-\int_{x}^\infty f_n(x)\,\mathbb{d}x \\
&< 1-\int_{x}^\infty h(x)\,\mathbb{d}x\\
&=H(x).
\end{align}$$.

In summary, $F_n(x)\leq H(x)$ for all $x$ with strict inequality at least for $x>x_0$, and we, again, established a stochastic order between $H$
and $F_n$. So, as in the previous case,
$$
\mu=\int_0^\infty 1-F_n(x)\,\mathbb{d}x > \int_0^\infty 1-H(x)\,\mathbb{d}x
=\mu_H=m.
$$
This confirms that $\mu>m$ for $n>2$, except for the $\lim_{t\rightarrow 0^+}r'(t)>0$ condition above to be verified.

To show $\lim_{t\rightarrow 0^+}r'(t)=1-\frac{n-2}m >0$, note that $n-2$ is the mode of $\chi^2_n$ distribution if $n>2$, and we only need to establish the "mode<median" inequality. (Actually, the "mode<media<mean" inequalities are usually stated together for "nice" distributions like the $\chi^2$ here.)
The proof follows the same idea of reflecting the pdf $f_n(x)$, but this time about the mode $n-2$. Define the reflected function $g$ by
$$
g(x)=\begin{cases}f_n(x),&\text{ if}\  0<x\leq n-2,\\
f_n\left[2(n-2)-x\right],&\text{ if}\ n-2<x<2(n-2),\\
0,&\text{ otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

Note that, as we well see later, unlike $h$, the function $g$ is not a density, since its integral is $<1$. First, we establish $g(x)<f_n(x)$ for $n-2<x<2(n-2)$ by similar arguments. For $0\leq t<n-2$, define the log ratio
$$
q(t)=\log\left\lbrace \frac{g[(n-2)+t]}{f_n[(n-2)+t]} \right\rbrace
=\log\left\lbrace  \frac{f_n[(n-2)-t]}{f_n[(n-2)+t]} \right\rbrace
$$
that simplifies to
$$
q(t)=t+\frac{n-2}{2} \log\left[ \frac{(n-2)-t}{(n-2)+t} \right],
$$
with its first derivative
$$q'(t) =\frac{t^2}{t^2-(n-2)^2} < 0\text{ for }0<t<n-2.
$$
Thus, starting from $q(0)=0$, the log ratio $q(t)$ decreases and $q(t)<0$ for all $0<t<n-2$. Namely, $g(x)<f_n(x)$ for $n-2<x<2(n-2)$.
Therefore, $g(x)\leq f_n(x)$ for all $x$ with strict inequality for $x>n-2$. Consequently, the total area under $g$ is strictly less than the total area $1$ under $f_n(x)$, and half of the area under $g$ is $<1/2$. But, by symmetry of $g$,
$$
\frac12\int_0^{2(n-2)}g(x)\,\mathbb{d}x=\int_{0}^{n-2}g(x)\,\mathbb{d}x = \int_{0}^{n-2}f_n(x)\,\mathbb{d}x <\frac12, 
$$where the last inequality means that the median $m$ is to the right of the mode $n-2$. This ensures that
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow 0^+}r'(t)=1-\frac{n-2}m >0.
$$

To sum up, $F_n(n)>\frac12$ for all $n\geq0$ in the a $\chi^2_n$ distribution. Although the details may vary,  the general idea of this proof is all about reflecting the pdf at some point of interest.
